# How can I configure create-react-app to create an app with classes and not functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am following a YouTube tutorial in order to learn React, but I noticed something annoying. When I create a new app with create-react-app, the app.js is using a `function App()`, and not a class. I know React can be coded both ways, but I would like to work with classes. Is there any way I can configure create-react-app to create a React app with classes? Something like adding an argument on the CLI, or maybe change an option on a setup page (I couldn't find any).

```
function App() {}
```

What I want:

```
class App extends Component {}
```

Comment: Why don't just change it to `class`?

Comment: You aren't locked in to either class or function you can mix and match, so you can change the app function to a class and every new component you create you can create as class.

Comment: I understand what both of you say, and I am perfectly aware that I can mix both notations. that was not my question :) I am looking for a way to make create-react-app to do it from start!

Comment: What you want to achieve is anti-pattern, as not all of your components need state nor need to be classes. If you’re looking for shorthand commands to create a boilerplate component class, then look into “snippets” for your IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are observing is not adjustable by configuration.  They changed the App.js generation in create-react-app from class to function with [commit e4fdac2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/e4fdac2418dbd1b3d51c8f0fecb474caa001f649#diff-9e2ecb03a0ec4155fbe42095c297a58e) and [commit b424737](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/b4247378a31292373457aed2266d4bc576779520#diff-9e2ecb03a0ec4155fbe42095c297a58e).  You are using a version of create-react-app more recent than the videos you are watching.  Either syntax is valid, depending on whether you need state or not, but you will have to alter the code yourself to use the former class syntax in App.js.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, I think it is a bit a shame, but if I can'tdo anything about it i'll edit it manually every time !

Answer (score 6):

If you would like your `create-react-app` to generate class instead of a function then you need to use the following command to create App with the older script version.

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version react-scripts@^2
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a solution to your problem. You just need an older version of react-scripts and your project configuration will fall back to using classes. When creating your project use this command:

```
create-react-app [Project Name] --scripts-version 2.0.3
```